# Rails 3: My smtp message headers won't take the :from => sender.email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email

so heres my info to start

config/initializers/mailer.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",  
  :user_name            => "myUser",  
  :password             => "secret",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

app/mailers/notifier.rb

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "My Company <info@mydomain.com>"

   def contact_notification(sender)
     @sender = sender
     mail(
         :to => "info@mydomain",
         :from => sender.email,
         :subject => "Message from #{sender.fullName} on Mydomain.com")
   end
end
```

My issue, whenever the emails get sent to me they show the smtp account as the from header email address instead of the senders email. So I can't just hit reply to reply to the senders email account.

Any Help would be appreciated.

***Up-Date***

With the the insite given I found a way to set the Reply-to email Header which did the trick.

Instead of using:

```
:from => sender.email,
```

I used

```
:reply_to => sender.email,
```

Hope this helps anyone else out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems specific to the gmail SMTP server see the information here:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

This is the applicable section:

> Note for IMAP/POP users: If you access Gmail through a POP or IMAP email client (e.g. Outlook) and would like to send messages with a custom "from" address, you have two options. We recommend that you configure your email client with two outgoing SMTP servers, one for Gmail and one for your other address. Your second option is to use Gmail's outbound servers with a different "from" address. If you've already configured the custom from address in the web interface, your message will be sent from:otheraddress@domain.com, sender:username@gmail.com, regardless of which custom from configuration you chose. Your messages will be sent from your regular Gmail address if you never configured your custom from settings in the web interface.

Other than setting that in the web interface for gmail as it suggests, have you tried the Reply-To header? That might work

Comment: my understanding is that setting :from => sender.email is setting the custom from address in the web interface. I've seen this in a few tutorials but for some reason its not taking premis when the emails get sent through the smtp

Comment: Specifying the :from would be like "selecting" the from address if it is already added to your gmail account. When I say setting in the web interface, I mean it seems that it needs to be entered into your Gmail Account settings under the "Accounts and Import" tab. If your sender address is going to be different each time, this is obviously not feasible, as you would need to add them all as available options.

Comment: I found the header for reply-to that works for rails 3 its  :reply_to